# Mostrar matriz horizontal con registros de tabla

Tags: php, mysql

En mi base de datos MySQL tengo algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase obtiene los registros

```
public function listarMatriz() {
    $sql = "SELECT  codigo, tipo, importe FROM tabla WHERE CONDICION";
    $bd = new Conn();
    $stmt = $bd->query($sql);

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    return $row;
}
```

Cómo hago para crear la matriz: `CODIGO, TIPO_A, TIPO_B, TIPO_C`
Y que los valores se muestren de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una consideración adicional es que el campo **TIPO** tiene una cantidad variable indeterminada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que buscas hacer es una tabla *Pivote* la cual puedes lograr del modo siguiente

```
SELECT codigo, 
SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = "a" THEN importe ELSE 0 END) AS "A",
SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = "b" THEN importe ELSE 0 END) AS "B",
SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = "c" THEN importe ELSE 0 END) AS "C"
FROM nombreTabla
GROUP BY codigo;
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. Selecciono la columna código
2. Hago uso de la función de agregación `SUM` para hacer una sumatoria de todos los valores pero cuando el `CASE` detecte cada caso en específico por ejemplo
3. Cuando detecte que la columna `tipo` es `a` entonces hará una sumatoria de la columna `importe` y al final por cada caso (que en este caso son 3) le asignamos un alias
4. Como usé una función de agregación `SUM` al final debo agrupar los resultados por una columna que en este caso es `codigo`

**Nota importante**

> Cambia en el `FROM` el nombre de la tabla por el que tu estas usando y así como te pasé el código debería estarte resultando

Opcionalmente si deseas agrupar los resultados puedes hacer lo siguiente en tu consulta

```
SELECT codigo, 
SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = "a" THEN importe ELSE 0 END) AS "A",
SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = "b" THEN importe ELSE 0 END) AS "B",
SUM(CASE WHEN tipo = "c" THEN importe ELSE 0 END) AS "C"
FROM demo
GROUP BY codigo
ORDER BY codigo;
```

Que te dará como resultado

```
codigo    A       B      C
10      100.00  170.00  0.00
20      340.00  25.00   280.00
30      0.00    38.00   139.00
40      250.00  450.00  0.00
50      0.00    310.00  75.00
```

Enlace al ejemplo funcional [ejemplo sql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=157bd004f54e6495f7335fc76cfcb3fb)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y funciona a la perfección, pero cómo sería si hubiera una cantidad indeterminada de valores en **tipo** ?

Comment: Disculpa al momento no tengo una respuesta para ese escenario aunque es interesante

Comment: La formularé en otra pregunta, y si es un caso interesante.