# ¿SQL worckbench? Hacer pivot

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el resultado del mismo nombre, lo coloque en la misma fila?

Consulta y resultado actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado esperado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mostrar matriz horizontal con registros de tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/242951/mostrar-matriz-horizontal-con-registros-de-tabla)

Comment: Hay vaaaarias preguntas sobre [pivot y mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=pivot%20%5bmysql%5d) aquí.

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo minimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, 
aqui las preguntas que no muestran algun intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, 
edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el 
[Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio 
y en [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo siguiente te puede ayudar a resolver tu problema:

> DBFiddle dónde lo probé: <kbd>**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/Omfb_MvT)**</kbd>

Primero cree una réplica de la tabla que tienes (solo algunos datos):

```sql
create table ejemplo
select *
from(
  values row('19lc826h','mai'), 
  row('19lc826h','main'),
  row('19lc826h','power'),
  row('19en33','ctr'),
  row('19en33','mai'),
  row('19m35a','ctr'),
  row('19m35a','mai')
)x(placa,modelo);

select * from ejemplo
```

Obteniendo por tabla lo siguiente:

```sql
+----------+--------+
| placa    | modelo |
+----------+--------+
| 19lc826h | mai    |
| 19lc826h | main   |
| 19lc826h | power  |
| 19en33   | ctr    |
| 19en33   | mai    |
| 19m35a   | ctr    |
| 19m35a   | mai    |
+----------+--------+
```

Lo próximo sería hacer una serie de CTE's:

```sql
with ejemplo_2 as 
(
select row_number() over(partition by placa order by placa) orden, 
  placa, modelo
  from ejemplo
),

ejemplo_3 as (
select
  placa,
  case when orden = 1 then modelo else null end panel_1,
  case when orden = 2 then modelo else null end panel_2,
  case when orden = 3 then modelo else null end panel_3
from ejemplo_2
  )
```

El primer CTE servirá para enumerar el orden de los modelos según placa y eso se logra haciendo uso de <kbd>**ROW_NUMBER**</kbd>; tras ello se realiza el ordenamiento según la columna nueva que creamos ('orden'), el tema con esto es que te resultará una tabla de la siguiente forma:

```sql
+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| placa    | panel_1 | panel_2 | panel_3 |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| 19en33   | ctr     | null    | null    |
| 19en33   | null    | mai     | null    |
| 19lc826h | mai     | null    | null    |
| 19lc826h | null    | main    | null    |
| 19lc826h | null    | null    | power   |
| 19m35a   | ctr     | null    | null    |
| 19m35a   | null    | mai     | null    |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Esta última tabla sería muy ineficiente y no lograría terminar de completar la solución a tú problema, para ello encontré una solución que puede te sirva y es la siguiente:

```sql
select *
from (
    select placa,
        panel_1,
        lead(panel_2,1) over(partition by placa order by placa) panel_2,
        lead(panel_3,2) over(partition by placa order by placa) panel_3
      from ejemplo_3
  ) x
where not x.panel_1 is null
```

Breve explicación de lo anterior (y última parte del script), usas <kbd>**LEAD**</kbd> para obtener la subsiguiente fila y como segundo parámetro si te fijas coloco 1 o 2 dependiendo desde qué fila espero me empiece a traer el valor subsiguiente.

La tabla final quedaría

```sql
+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| placa    | panel_1 | panel_2 | panel_3 |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| 19en33   | ctr     | mai     | null    |
| 19lc826h | mai     | main    | power   |
| 19m35a   | ctr     | mai     | null    |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

> Finalmente, a mi entender PIVOT no sirve en este caso puesto que los valores a traer no son agrupables como si lo son valores, promedios, sumas, etc.

Saludos.

Comment: Si vas a usar LEAD(), lo puedes usar directamente y ahorrarte varios pasos, incluido el dar un número a cada fila.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio de muchas ayudad tu respuesta. Te agrades o que te ayas tomado el tiempo para responder y dar una explicacion muy detallada